# execute extra observable/promise at the end of the http request

Tags: rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs6

I have an interceptor and I need to chain/execute a promise/observable when the request comes back from the server.  How can I do this in rxjs 6?

```
intercept(): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)[DO-SOMETHING]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to modify the http event:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    mergeMap(request => yourPromiseOrObservable));
```

What does `mergeMap` do?

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable.

[And for more help](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

If you don't need to modify the http event:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    tap(request => yourPromise.then(_ => ;)));
```

What does `tap` do?

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return
>    an Observable that is identical to the source.

Or, if you need to wait for the promise but don't modify the request:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    delayWhen(request => from(yourPromise)));
```

What does `delayWhen` do?

> Delays the emission of items from the source Observable by a given time span determined by the emissions of another Observable.

Comment: My promise returns Promise<void>. The compiler gives an error on this because the function expects  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> :(

Comment: I see, you don't need the result of the inner observable? Then use `tap`. I've added it to my post.

Comment: Yea but I need to wait for that observable/promise before code continues. Tap is just doing an action on it and not necesserally wait for it...

Comment: Ok we are close by :)   Now in the delayWhen i need to only perform the promise in case 'request instanceof HttpResponse'. Should i perform an if else check in the delayWhen and return empty() in case nothing has to be done? Or is there a smarter way?

Comment: I think that should do it. There are ways doing it with the `filter` operator, but this would complicate reading your code. Using the ternary operator "?" you can do a oneliner... `request instanceof HttpResponse ? from(yourPromise) : empty()`